# How to put damping and friction to a bouncing ball?

Tags: java, processing

I just made a code with a bouncing ball. It works fine but, it doesn't slow down. What I want is to put a fricition (20%) and every time when the ball bounces on the edge, it should slow down (0.2%) till it stops and turn black.

My Code:

```
float posX = 300;
float posY = 200;
float speedY= 2;
float speedX = 5;
float ballsize = 25;
float damping = 0.2;
color red = color(255,0,0);
color green = color(0,255,0);
color black = color(0);
color ballcolor; 


void setup() {
  size(600, 400);
  background(191);
  surface.setTitle("ball");
  surface.setLocation((displayWidth-width)>>1, (displayHeight-height)>>1);
}
void draw() {
background(191);
  posX = posX + speedX;
  posY = posY + speedY;

  if (posX > width) {
    speedX = speedX* -1;
    ballcolor = (ballcolor == red ? green : red);
  }

  if (posX < 0) {
    speedX = speedX* -1;
    ballcolor = (ballcolor == red ? green : red);
  }

  if (posY > height) {
    speedY= speedY* -1;
    ballcolor = (ballcolor == red ? green : red);
  }

  if (posY < 0) {
    speedY= speedY* -1;
    ballcolor = (ballcolor == red ? green : red);
  }

  if (abs(speedY) < 0.1 && abs(speedX) < 0.1) {
 speedX = 0;
 speedY = 0;
}

  fill(ballcolor);
  ellipse(posX, posY, ballsize, ballsize);
}
```

Comment: Just decrease your speed variables by 20%: `speedX*=0.8` for example

Comment: Thank you! It worked. But how do I add a friction?

Comment: Well then that's a different problem. You can clamp the ball's position to the bounds of the frame by setting its position directly when that occurs